# Is 5.45GB normal for Project Build and Index in Xcode?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, xcode

Today I ran a Xcode project on a react-native project, and it add up to 5.43 GB for only one simple project, is that normal? So if I have 10 projects it will add up to 50 GB??!!?

[image: Screenshot of directory size]

In Android, it eats up 12 GB for the SDK but it does not consume anymore space, but Xcode eats up 5 gigs a project... Is that normal? I tried to create new project and it added up to 9 GB.

I deleted this project and it added up again. Is there any solution for this?

I ran on Xcode 12, MacOS 11.5.1, MacBook Pro M1.

Answer (score 0):

The "Project Build Data and Indexes" entry you see there is combined for all your projects. As you create new projects, I wouldn't expect each of them to increase the amount of disk space used by the same amount as the first - i.e. various caches, pre-built data and indices are only needed once (or once per architecture, once per device model, once per iOS version or similar).

Whether or not 5 GB of data for a single Xcode project is "normal" is impossible to say. Some projects take up 50 kB of disk space, some takes up 50 GB - it really depends on the specific project.

Comment: omg, this project is default project when i create by `npx react-native init MyProject`, and eat up 5bg, maybe 256gb is not enough for dev, but i have one question: if i move project to extenal ssd , how can i move all data to this ssd?

Comment: React Native is known for having these huge project sizes as it draws in lots and lots of dependencies. You’ll have a different experience with projects not based on React Native.

Comment: You can move the project itself simply by dragging the folder to the other SSD in Finder